# htaccess root/subfolder and root/subfolder/ into root/subfolder2/subfolder/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to be able to enter the following into the URL:

https://mydomain.com/fork
or 
https://mydomain.com/fork/

And for both to goto a subfolder called

https://mydomain.com/prod/fork_contents/index.html

But still only display https://mydomain.com/fork (or https://mydomain.com/fork/, either way)

I would like index.html to act as the root so all the image urls, etc still work (they are relative to '/prod/fork_contents/')

Currently the .htaccess in the root is:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /live/site_documents/document404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /live/site_documents/accessDenied.html


Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$

RewriteRule ^fork$ /fork/index.html [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^fork/$ /fork/index.html [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^fork/(.*)$ /prod/forklift_contents/$1 [L,QSA]
```

- https://mydomain.com/fork/ Works fine!
- https://mydomain.com/fork Doesn't work. The index.html loads, but it can't find any of the files. Firebug's net panel reports the following 'https://mydomain.com/css/style.css not found'. So the second case (without the trailing /) doesn't seem to know to go into https://mydomain.com/fork/css/style.css.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the question mark for optional charters

```
RewriteRule ^fork\/? /prod/fork/$1 [L]
```

For a very good tutorial on rewriting check this website
[.htaccess tips and tricks..](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)